# Two classes with member functions taking a pointer to an object from the other class

Tags: c++

```
class a {
public:
void f2(b * elem);
};

class b {
public:
void f1(a * elem);
};
```

There will be a problem here.

```
void f2(b * elem);
```

How do I declare class `b` in such a way that I can use function `f2`?

Comment: Forward declaration

Comment: Yes you can. What's the problem?

Comment: in my simple code there is an error syntax error:identifier b ; the compiler does not know who is b, so how do i make it work?

Comment: Did you separate them into .h file and .cpp file? Or just one file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tell the compiler that there is a class a and b. But don't tell him/her how they look like :) It is possible because you work with pointers. Its only a integer for the compiler. Later you can define all the functions of the classes and the compile will be happy to know now how they look like.

```
class a; // tell the compiler there is a class a
class b; // tell the compiler there is a class b

// real implementation of class a
class a {
    public:
        void f2(b * elem);
};

// real implementation of class b
class b {
    public:
        void f1(a * elem);
};
```